# What's wrong with my Python code for a vanity plate checker?

Tags: python, format

Alright, I'm stuck. Should be a simple Vanity Plate code, but for some reason its only giving me Invalids, tried to cheat the autograder system and its still not working with me. What am I missing?

```
def main():
    # Prompt the user for a vanity plate
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def is_valid(s):
    # Check if the plate meets all reqs
    return (
        has_valid_length(s) and
        has_valid_format(s) and
        has_valid_characters(s)
    )

def has_valid_length(s):
    # Check if the plate has a length of 6 char
    return len(s) == 6

def has_valid_characters(s):
    # Check if the plate  only has alphanumeric characters
    return s.isalnum()

def has_valid_format(s):
    # Check if the plate matches the specific formats "CS50" or "ECTO88",
    # or if it has two characters followed by digits
    return s in ["CS50", "ECTO88"] or (s[:2].isalpha() and s[2:].isdigit())

main()
```

Tried to change the retun, restructed my methods, tried to just exclude the specific text and still no go.

Comment: Including some example tests with expected output can help clarify here.

Comment: `"CS50"` will fail the `len(s) == 6` test.

Comment: Maybe it's supposed to be `len(s) <= 6`?

Comment: Please post the requirement specification. We can't tell if you're implementing it correctly without knowing what they are.

Comment: My bad the specifics are "Implement a program that prompts the user for a vanity plate and then output Valid if meets all of the requirements or Invalid if it does not. Assume that any letters in the user’s input will be uppercase. Structure your program per the below, wherein is_valid returns True if s meets all requirements and False if it does not. Assume that s will be a str. You’re welcome to implement additional functions for is_valid to call (e.g., one function per requirement)."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.